# Azure Service Bus - The only supported IsolationLevel is 'IsolationLevel.Serializable'

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azureservicebus

I'm trying to push a message to a topic on the Azure Service Bus, but when I do so, I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The only supported IsolationLevel is 'IsolationLevel.Serializable'.
  Source=Microsoft.ServiceBus
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpResourceManager.EnlistAsyncResult..ctor(SbmpResourceManager resourceManager, Transaction transaction, IRequestSessionChannel channel, SbmpMessageCreator messageCreator, Action`1 partitionInfoSetter, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpResourceManager.BeginEnlist(Transaction transaction, IRequestSessionChannel channel, SbmpMessageCreator messageCreator, Action`1 partitionInfoSetter, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpTransactionalAsyncResult`1.<>c__DisplayClass38.<GetAsyncSteps>b__32(TIteratorAsyncResult thisPtr, TimeSpan t, AsyncCallback c, Object s)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType state)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.Start()
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.EndSendCommand(IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.OnEndSend(IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.EnumerateSteps(CurrentThreadType state)
    Exception rethrown at [1]: 
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.RunSynchronously()
       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.Send(TrackingContext trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 messages, TimeSpan timeout)
       at CryptoArb.Infrastructure.AzureStorage.ServiceBus.AzureServiceBusService.Send(String label, Object message)
```

The service bus code is below:

```
public class AzureServiceBusService : IServiceBusService
{
    public ISettingsService SettingsService { get; set; }
    private NamespaceManager _namespaceManager;
    private string _topic;
    private TopicClient _topicClient;
    private TopicDescription _topicDescription;
    private string _connectionString;
    private SubscriptionClient _subscriptionClient;
    private string _subscriptionName = "AllMessages";

    public string Topic
    {
        get { return _topic; }
        set
        {
            _topic = value;
            _topicDescription = null;
            _topicClient = null;
        }

    }
    public SubscriptionClient SubscriptionClient
    {
        get
        {
            if (_subscriptionClient != null) return _subscriptionClient;
            if (!NamespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(TopicDescription.Path, _subscriptionName))
                NamespaceManager.CreateSubscription(TopicDescription.Path, _subscriptionName);
            _subscriptionClient = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, TopicDescription.Path,
                _subscriptionName);

            return _subscriptionClient;
        }
    }


    internal string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_connectionString))
                _connectionString = SettingsService.ConnectionStrings[SettingsService.MainServiceBusConfigName].ConnectionString;

            return _connectionString;
        }
    }


    internal TopicClient TopicClient
    {
        get {
            return _topicClient ??
                   (_topicClient = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, TopicDescription.Path));
        }
    }

    internal TopicDescription TopicDescription
    {
        get
        {
            if (_topicDescription != null) return _topicDescription;
            if (!NamespaceManager.TopicExists(_topic))
                NamespaceManager.CreateTopic(_topic);
            _topicDescription = NamespaceManager.GetTopic(_topic);
            return _topicDescription;
        }
    }

    internal NamespaceManager NamespaceManager
    {
        get {
            if (_namespaceManager == null)
            {
                _namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);
                _namespaceManager.Settings.RetryPolicy = RetryExponential.Default;
            }
            return _namespaceManager;
        }
    }

    public AzureServiceBusService()
    {
        _topic = "default";
    }
    public AzureServiceBusService(string topic)
    {
        _topic = topic;
    }

    public void Send(string label, object message)
    {
        var brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message)
        {
            Label = label,
        };
        brokeredMessage.Properties["messageType"] = message.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
        TopicClient.Send(brokeredMessage);
    }

    public ServiceBusMessage Receive()
    {
        var receivedMessage = SubscriptionClient.Receive();
        if (receivedMessage == null)
            return null;
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Type messageBodyType = null;
                if (receivedMessage.Properties.ContainsKey("messageType"))
                    messageBodyType = Type.GetType(receivedMessage.Properties["messageType"].ToString());
                if (messageBodyType == null)
                {
                    //Should never get here as a messagebodytype should
                    //always be set BEFORE putting the message on the queue
                    receivedMessage.DeadLetter();
                }
                var method = typeof(BrokeredMessage).GetMethod("GetBody", new Type[] { });
                var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(messageBodyType);
                var messageBody = generic.Invoke(receivedMessage, null);
                var serviceBusMessage = new ServiceBusMessage()
                {
                    Body = messageBody,
                    MessageId = receivedMessage.MessageId
                };

                receivedMessage.Complete();
                return serviceBusMessage;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                receivedMessage.Abandon();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public string SubscriptionName
    {
        get { return _subscriptionName; }
        set { _subscriptionName = value; }
    }
}
```

I have ensured that the connection string to the service bus is valid and checks are in place to ensure that topics and subscriptions exists before trying to utilize them.

Why am I getting the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are not under another transaction.
To isolate your code with it's own IsolationLevel, you can wrap it with

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
        new TransactionOptions {IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable}))
{
    ...sending to the queue

    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Suppressing the transaction is also an option :)

Answer (score 2):

Does the code which call Send method create a TransactionScope? If so, please make sure the isolotaionLevel is set to Serializable.

Comment: No... It doesn't create a TransactionScope. Shoud it be?